# select column in database by ID using LINQ and WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, linq

I'm trying to populate a webform on a jQuery UI modal when someone clicks on an edit button with data from a database using AJAX to call the method getProjectByID() and populate the webform on the modal. I think I'm close but definitely missing some stuff. I basically want to get the ten or so columns from clicked row with a ProjectID, return them with JSON then parse the JSON and populate the corresponding textboxes in the modal with the column in the table.

AJAX Call:

```
var id = $(this).attr('value'); //this is the id of the clicked row

    $.ajax({
        url: "view-requests.aspx/getProjectByID",   // Current Page, Method
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }), // parameter map as JSON
        type: "POST", // data has to be POSTed
        contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content    
        dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)
        timeout: 10000,    // AJAX timeout
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);
            $("#txtContactFirstEdit").val(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string getProjectByID(int id)
    {
        using (dbPSREntities4 myEntities = new dbPSREntities4())
        {
            var thisProject = from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.tbProject == id) // this is not correct but close?
                              select tbProject;
            return thisProject.ToList(); //no idea how to return it...
        }
    }
```

In the AJAX I want to populate the textbox but I don't now how to parse the JSON to get out the values.

Any help on this would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first your LINQ will work, but you can simply it removing unnecessary parts. At second, you need to use some serializer, for example the one already shipped in the System.Web, and turn your data into JSON:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getProjectByID(int id)
{
    var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.tbProject == id).ToList();

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(thisProject);

    return json;
}
```

Actually if your LINQ query is supposed to return just one object, not a collection, you can do your JSON even simpler:

```
var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.tbProject == id).Single(); // or SingleOrDefault - depends on your situation
...
var json = serializer.Serialize(thisProject);
```

This will give you the JSON describing just the project object, without array overhead.

Comment: It's giving me a red underline at (x => x.tbProject == id) saying Delegate System.Func<dbPSRModel.tbProject,int,bool> does not take 1 arguments.

Comment: any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @user1431633, well, it seems that actually there should be something like `tbProjects.Where(x => x.ID == id)`, since `x` is already of an instance of Project.

Answer (score 1):

I good start for that you can find here: http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/csharp-serialize-object-to-json-format-using-javascriptserialization

As I can see you are trying to return a List of Objects to the Client, but your WebMethod is set to return a string, right? So why don't serialize it?

```
string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(thisProject);

return json;
```

For me the right could be return the entire list of objects to the client as an Array